# MySQL date_format showing '1st', '2nd', '3rd'

Tags: mysql

I'm making a change to my date outputs and trying to show nd, rd, st, etc., like 1st September 2013 or 3rd. Looking at the manual 'jS' should do it but it is just outputting nonsense. Does anyone know what are the correct letter(s) to use?

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, "%jS %M %Y") AS Displaydate
```

EDIT: my bad, I thought date_format was PHP not MySQL - sorry.

Comment: You really didn't make it clear that you are trying to change something in an SQL query...

Comment: Both php and MySQL have a date_format() function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

If you read the docs you would see that using %D shows the Day Suffix

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, "%D") as suffix
```

Would produce the '2nd' or '1st', etc.